# Installing Android OS on SD card

Tags: external-sd, installation, operating-system

I am not using Android smartphone till now. I want to install the Android OS on SD card and use this SD card to boot Android on same line of smartphones.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Thanks Shambleh and Matt for your replies. <br>
Matt; I have seen 3 OS on Nokia N900 cell phone. 2 of them were installed on the cell phone device and the 3rd one was FroYo. But again I am not sure how that person did that. You can also get youtube videos on installing android on N900. I just got to know that we have to use 'git' and 'repo' to install android. <br><br>
Can you please help me and explain how to use 'git' and 'repo'? Let me tell you that I am very new to development. Any help or information you give will be very helpful.<br><br>
Thank you. :)

Comment: In what phone?, if you have a HTC HD2 this is possible and very easy, but it will depend on what phone you have.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is possible if your phone has an unlocked bootloader and you are capable of modifying it.  I have no idea how to do this but you may find help on Stack Overflow.  You can also check out how the devs that install Android on Windows phones do it.  [This site](http://www.androidonhtc.com/wiki/Installing_Android#SDCard_Install) talks about installing Android on the SD card for their dual-boot mod.

This is probably more work than it's worth.  Another option, if you are going to be using it on the same exact model of phone and they are rooted: Use [Titanium Backup](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to backup all the apps and settings and then restore them to another phone.  This can be done to the SD or to Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is at all possible.  Individual apps for Android may be able to be moved to a SD card (Froyo and above required as well as an app that allows this) but the entire OS cannot live on an SD card.